# How to delete content of a log file from linux terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal

I have a log file on server called `writelog` which is about `2GB`.

I want to delete first `100,000` lines from the file. I could open the file and delete those lines but because of the file size it takes me forever to download it.

So, is it possible to do this from Linux terminal? If yes how?

Comment: you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112469/delete-specific-line-numbers-from-a-text-file-using-sed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running a Linux server, you can use `ssh`:

```
ssh username@mydomain.com sed -i '1,100000d' /path/to/logfile
```

Answer (score 13):

If you want to clear out the *whole file* a quick way is

`cat /dev/null > writelog`

See also [this thread on unix.com](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/150082-create-empty-file-overwrite-file-differences-between-cat-echo-etc.html).

Comment: @Bala That depends on your shell settings ... A better way of doing this is: `: >| writelog` to override the `-C`/`noclobber` option ... in C shell, this is: `: >! writelog`... The `:` is the built-in "null command", which does nothing, outputs nothing, and always exits 0.

Answer (score 7):

It might be better to keep the last 1000 lines:

```
mv writelog writelog.bak
tail -1000 writelog.bak > writelog
```

And you should enable `logrotate` ([manual](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)) for the file. The system will then make sure the file doesn't grow out of proportions.