# Output matching lines in linux

Tags: bash

I want to match the numbers in the first file with the 2nd column of second file and get the matching lines in a separate output file. Kindly let me know what is wrong with the code?

I have a list of numbers in a file IDS.txt

```
10028615
1003
10096344
10100
10107393
10113978
10163178
118747520
```

I have a second File  called src1src22.txt

```
From src:'1'    To src:'22'
CHEMBL3549542   118747520
CHEMBL548732    44526300
CHEMBL1189709   11740251
CHEMBL405440    44297517
CHEMBL310280    10335685
```

expected newoutput.txt

```
CHEMBL3549542   118747520
```

I have written this code

```
while read line; do cat src1src22.txt | grep -i -w "$line"  >> newoutput.txt done<IDS.txt
```

Comment: *what is wrong with the code* What is the Output you get and what is the Output you expecting

Comment: kindly observe the expected output. I do not get any output.

Comment: whenever I see this I ask if bash is requirement, because even it is possible to do it in bash; it's not efficient in text processing; as your platform is linux, you definitely have python that suits much better this task.

Comment: Repeatedly looping over `grep` is horribly inefficient. Joining two files is a common task; the canonical duplicate is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272717/inner-join-on-two-text-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command line works - except you're missing a semicolon:

```
while read line; do grep -i -w "$line" src1src22.txt; done < IDS.txt >> newoutput.txt
```

Comment: You should still add the missing quotes, and probably move the output redirection outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an efficient way to perform the task. Instead of a loop try this -f gives the pattern in the file next to it and searches in the next file. The chance of invalid character length which can occur with grep is reduced and looping slows the process down.

```
 grep -iw -f IDS.txt src1src22.tx >>newoutput.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next} $1 in a{print a[$1],$0}' f2 f1
CHEMBL3549542 118747520
```

Where f2 is src1src22.txt