# Partially match to words from two different files and extract rows sed,awk,grep?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have two different files that I want to partially match one number from the first one with another number from the other one and extract the whole column.

File1:

```
smt_hsa_3150    932
smt_hsa_28592   682
smt_hsa_5184    657
smt_hsa_430 648
smt_hsa_14100   648
smt_hsa_96 648
```

File2:

```
chr11 5933549 5933577 29 + hsa_smt_028592
chr11 45693060 45693086 27 - hsa_smt_000059
chr11 45699803 45699832 30 - hsa_smt_000087
chr2 131291172 131291197 26 - hsa_smt_000096
```

I need to match smt_hsa_28592 or 28592 with hsa_smt_028592 or 028592.
and then extract to a new file the line from the second file plus the number from 2nd column of the 1st file.

output:

```
chr11 5933549 5933577 29 + hsa_smt_028592 682   
chr2 131291172 131291197 26 - hsa_smt_000096 648
```

As I'm new to awk/sed programming I tried first to change the name of the first column of the 1st file from smt_hsa_3150 to hsa_smt_3150, but when I perform

```
awk '{gsub("smt","hsa")}1'
```

then, I cannot use the same code to change only the second "hsa".
The second problem is how I would be able to match hsa_smt_028592 with smt_has_28592 or smt_hsa_96 with  hsa_smt_000096.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inner join on two text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272717/inner-join-on-two-text-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fun using join :

```
join -11 -26 -o 2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,1.1,1.2 <(awk -F' +|_' '{printf "hsa_smt_%06s %s\n", $3, $4}' file1.txt | sort -k1) <(sort -k6 file2.txt)
```

awk command is formatting the first column of your file1 in same format as file2. Then we join the two files (first we need to sort them both).

---

`awk -F' *|_'` -> I split on multiple spaces and "_" character

`'{printf "hsa_smt_%06s %s\n", $3, $4}'` -> I print hsa_smt_< third column as an integer of width 6 > <4th column>. Awk will add leading zeros if needed

`sort -k6 file2` or `awk ... | sort -k1` I sort the files on 6th or 1st columns

`join -11 -26 -o 2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,1.1,1.2` I join the files on the first column for file 1 (`-11`) and 6th column for file 2 (`-26`) then I order the columns (`2.1` -> 1st column of file2, etc...)

---

Pure awk solution :

```
awk 'NR==FNR{split($1,s,"_");smt[s[3]+0]=$2;next}{split($6,s,"_");k=s[3]+0}k in smt{print $0, smt[k]}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

In this solution, I split smt_hsa_xxx and hsa_smt_xxx, convert the 3rd part to integers so I can compare them.

---

`NR==FNR{split($1,s,"_");smt[s[3]+0]=$2;next}` this block will be executed only on file1 because of the `NR==FNR` [condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481877/what-is-nr-fnr-in-awk). It splits the first column, convert the smt_hsa id to integer (doing  +0 is a classic way to convert string to integer in awk), then stores second column inside an array named smt.

`next;` prevents executing the other blocks for file1

`{split($6,s,"_");k=s[3]+0}` this block will [split](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) the 6th column of file2, convert the id to integer. We could have used " +|_" as delimiter to avoid splitting columns (see first solution).

`k in smt{print $0, smt[k]}` will check if the id is a key of smt array. Then it prints line from file2 and second column of file1 (which was stored in smt)

---

I'm pretty sure that the second solution is more performant but may be greedier in memory.

Both give same output, order of lines may differ :

```
chr11 5933549 5933577 29 + hsa_smt_028592 682
chr2 131291172 131291197 26 - hsa_smt_000096 648
```

Comment: Thank you very much, is it possible to have a small explanation about each step of awk?

Comment: I added some explanations, do not hesitate to comment if you have any questions @K.Gele

Comment: I have another question regarding joining two files but it will be marked as a duplicate. How should I proceed?

Comment: @KGeles if it is set as duplicate that's because you can get your answer already somewhere ?