# Using "comm" to find matches between two arrays

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I have two arrays, I am trying to find matching values using `comm`. `Array1` contains some additional information in each element that I strip out for the comparison. However, I would like to keep that information after the comparison is complete.

For example:

```
Array1=("abc",123,"hello" "def",456,"world")
Array2=("abc")
declare -a Array1
declare -a Array2
```

I then compare the two arrays:

```
oldIFS=$IFS IFS=$'\n\t'
array3=($(comm -12 <(echo "${Array1[*]}" | awk -F "," {'print $1'} | sort) <(echo "${Array2[*]}" | sort)))
IFS=$oldIFS
```

Which finds the match of `abc`:

```
echo ${test3[0]}
abc
```

However what I want is remaining values from array1 that were not part of my `comm` statement.

```
abc,123,hello
```

---

**EDIT: For more clarification**

The arrays in this example are populated with dummy data.

My real example is pulling information from server logs which I am saving into array1. array1 contains (userIDs,hostIPs,count) that I want to cross reference against a list of userID's (array2). My goal is to find out what userIDs exsist in array1 and array2 and save those ID's with the additional information from array1 (hostIPs,count) into array3

array1 is populated from a variable that is is the results of a curl command that generates a splunk search. The data returned looks like this:

```
"uniqueID=<ID>","<IP>","<hostname>",1
```

I save the results of the splunk report as $splunk, and then decalare array1 with the results of $splunk - the header information since the results come back in csv format

```
array1=( $(echo $splunk | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sed 1d) )
```

array2 is generated from a master file that I have stored locally. That contains all the application ID's in our ecosystem. For example

```
uid=<ID>
```

I cat the contents of the master file into array2

```
array2=( $(cat master.txt) )
```

I then want to find what IDs from array1 exsist in array2 and save that as array3. This requires some massaging of the data in array1 to make it match the format of array2.

```
oldIFS=$IFS IFS=$'\n\t'
array3=($(comm -12 <(echo "${array1[*]}" | sed 's/ /\n/g' | awk -F "\"," {'print $1'} | sed 's/\"//g' | sed 's/|/ /g' | awk -F$'=' -v OFS=$'=' '{ $1 = "uid" }1' | grep -i "OU=People" | sed 's/OU/ou/g' | sort) <(echo "${array2[*]}" | sort)))
IFS=$oldIFS
```

array 3 will then contain lines that match in both arrays

```
uid=<ID>
uid=<ID>
```

However I am looking for something more along the line of

```
"uid=<ID>","<IP>","<hostname>",1
"uid=<ID>","<IP>","<hostname>",1
```

Comment: why not `"def",456,"world"` as well?  Also what prevents you using `Array1`?

Comment: edited question for more clarification

Comment: How do you define these arrays?

Comment: I mean, how exactly do you assign to the dummy arrays? It's not clear if you assume elements are comma or space separated.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I save the arrays from the values of variables that are declared earlier in my script 
array1=( $(echo $logdata ) ) ; array2=( $(echo $userIDs) )

Comment: They are space separated with real data and dummy data

Comment: Can you edit the question with commands such that the arrays are created with the exact dummy data your question refers to?

Comment: Using `comm` for this seems weird. A common technique is to use Awk to join information from two files which contain different data but the same keys. A starting point is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272717/inner-join-on-two-text-files

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I meant you should edit the question to make it such that I can test here. Instead of `Array1{ "abc",123,"hello" "def",456,"world" }` something like `Array1=(abc,123,hello def,456,world)` (or should it be `(abc 123 hello def 456 world)`?). With your notation, I don't know what *really* is in the arrays.

Comment: @BenjaminW. lol sorry updated again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
join -t, \
    <(printf '%s\n' "${Array1[@]}" | sort -t, -k1,1) \
    <(printf '%s\n' "${Array2[@]}" | sort)
```

Use the `join` command with `,` as the field delimiter. The first "file" is the first array, one element per line, sorted on the first field (comma delimited); the second "file" is the second array, one element per line, sorted.

The output will be every line where the first element of the first file matches the element from the second file; for the example input it's

```
abc,123,hello
```

---

This makes only one assumption, namely that no array element contains a newline. To make it more robust (assuming GNU Coreutils), we can use NUL as the delimiter:

```
join -z -t, \
    <(printf '%s\0' "${Array1[@]}" | sort -z -t, -k1,1) \
    <(printf '%s\0' "${Array2[@]}" | sort -z)
```

This prints the output separated by NUL as well; to read the result into an array, we can use `readarray`:

```
readarray -d '' -t Array3 < <(
    join -z -t, \
        <(printf '%s\0' "${Array1[@]}" | sort -z -t, -k1,1) \
        <(printf '%s\0' "${Array2[@]}" | sort -z)
)
```

`readarray -d` requires Bash 4.4 or newer. For older Bash, you can use a loop:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' element; do
    Array3+=("$element")
done < <(
    join -z -t, \
        <(printf '%s\0' "${Array1[@]}" | sort -z -t, -k1,1) \
        <(printf '%s\0' "${Array2[@]}" | sort -z)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this with `comm`, but I do have a solution for you with `sed` and `grep`. The following commands match on the regex `uid=X,`, where the string/array is in the form of `uid=x` or `(uid=x uid=y)` respectively.

```sh
# Array 2 (B) is a string
$ A=("uid=1,10.10.10.1,server1,1" "uid=2,10.10.10.2,server2,1")
$ B="uid=1"
$ echo ${A[@]} | grep -oE "([^ ]*${B},[^ ]*)"
uid=1,10.10.10.1,server1,1

# Array 2 (D) is an array
$ C=(${A[@]} "uid=3,10.10.10.3,server3,1" "uid=4,10.10.10.4,server4,1")
$ D=(${B} "uid=3")
$ echo ${C[*]} | grep -oE "([^ ]*($(echo ${D[@]} | sed 's/ /,|/g'))[^ ]*)"
uid=1,10.10.10.1,server1,1
uid=3,10.10.10.3,server3,1

# Content of arrays
$ echo ${A[@]}
uid=1,10.10.10.1,server1,1 uid=2,10.10.10.2,server2,1
$ echo ${B}
uid=1
$ echo ${C[@]}
uid=1,10.10.10.1,server1,1 uid=2,10.10.10.2,server2,1 uid=3,10.10.10.3,server3,1 uid=4,10.10.10.4,server4,1
$ echo ${D[@]}
uid=1 uid=3
```