# Print all lines except those matching a variable with awk

Tags: awk

I have the following for getting the lines matching a variable using awk:

```
for i in `cat file1`; do awk -v id="$i" '$0 ~ id' file2; done
```

How can I do the opposite?
Getting the lines that DON'T match? I think I should use ! somewhere, but don't know where.

File 1 looks like this:

```
5NX1D
5NX3D
4NTYB
```

File 2 looks like this:

```
2R9PA IVGGYTCEENS
2RA3C RPDFCLEPPYT
6HARE YVDYKDDDDKE
4NTYB EYVDYKDDDDD
```

Output should look like this:

```
2R9PA IVGGYTCEENS
2RA3C RPDFCLEPPYT
6HARE YVDYKDDDDKE
```

Comment: Could you please post samples of input and expected output(not my downvote btw), thank you.

Comment: Thanks for edit so you want to compare 1st fields of both the files? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: Yes that's right. I want to remove from file2 the lines that contain the fields in file1

Comment: ok sure, could you please post expected output in your question, that will make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32747544/1435869

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: What I think Ravinder tries to ask is, should we remove a line which contains a match only in the second field? Your prose description seems to say yes, but your example looks like the opposite, and usually that would make more sense in most scenarios.

Comment: In other words. if the first line were `2R9PA randomrandom5NX1Drandomrandom`, should that be deleted, or kept? (You probably have much longer second fields if you hre working with bioinformatics, so it's not entriely unlikely that the second field could contain a substring match somewhere within it.

Comment: It should be kept. I'm only comparing first fields in both files. The second field is meant to be a looong sequence that I want to retain in my output. And yeah I'm precisely working with bioinformatics :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the standard [inner join,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272717) except we print if a match was *not* found.

```sh
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1]; next }
    !($1 in a)' file1 file2 >newfile2
```

This is very standard Awk idiom all the way, but very briefly, the line number within the current file `FNR` will be equal to the overall input line number `NR` while we are traversing the first input file, `file1`. If so, we add its contents to the array `a`, and skip to the next line. Else, if we fall through, we are no longer in the first file; we print if the first field `$1` is not in `a`.

Your original script would be more idiomatic and a lot more efficient phrased similarly (just without the `!`), too.

Comment: I'm still a newbie using awk. Could you please explain to me how this works?

Comment: I added a brief explanation.