# Delete specific line up to the last

Tags: unix, sed

I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112469/delete-specific-line-numbers-from-a-text-file-using-sed) on removing specific lines, but how about from a specific line up to the end of the file?

My guesses (wrong though):

```
sed -e '2d-$d' foo
```

while this removes the 2nd and last line:

```
sed -e '2d;$d' foo
```

Comment: Ranges are specified by commas. `2,$d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct expression is

```
sed -e '2,$d' foo
```

I.e. For all lines from line 2 to the last line, delete.

Comment: Oh, it was just the additional `d`!