# Using sed to replace entire phrase

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, sh

I'm using ShellScript to edit my bind dns configuration file, when add and remove zone references.
Then in "master.conf" file we have this content:

```
...
...
zone "mydomain.com" {
   type master; 
   file "/var/zones/m/mydomain.com"
};
...
...
```

I want "remove" this entry to "mydomain.com" using "sed", but I could'n write a correct regex to this. The expression must use variable domain name and search until next close bracket and semicolon, something like this:

```
DOMAIN_NAME="mydomain.com"
sed -i.bak -r 's/^zone "'$DOMAIN_NAME'" \{(.*)\};$//g' /var/zones/master.conf
```

See that we should ignore the content between brackets, and this chunk have to replaced with "nothing".
I tried some variations of this expression, but without success.

Comment: rather dangerous regex, since `(.*)` is going to suck up everything until the **LAST** `}` in the file. you could potentially nuke all the zones in the file.

Comment: @Mark its only to next close bracket. I already change the text from question. Thanks from your note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use awk?

```
awk -v dom="mydomain.com" '$2 ~ dom, /^};$/ {next}1' file
```

The `,` is the range operator. The range is true between the lines with `dom` in the second field and the line that only contains "};". `next` skips those lines. The rest are printed.

Use `awk '...' file > tmp && mv tmp file` to overwrite the original file.

Comment: Yes, I can use awk. But when I try your hint, the result output was the record entry. In my question I want **remove** this chunk of text from file, replacing it with '' (empty string).

Comment: The whole point of the script is that it skips the entry (that's what `next` does). It works for me using your sample input.

Comment: Tom, your solution works fine too and was more elegant in my script. I was hasty with my previous comment. Tanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below sed script it should work

**Code:**

```
sed -i '/"mydomain.com" [{]/{
:loop
N
s/[}][;]/&/
t end
b loop
:end
d
}' master.conf
```

**Input:**

```
zone "myd.com" {
   type master;
   file "/var/zones/m/mydomain.com"

};
zone "mydomain.com" {
   type master;
   file "/var/zones/m/mydomain.com"
};
```

**Output:**

```
zone "myd.com" {
       type master;
       file "/var/zones/m/mydomain.com"

    };
```

Comment: Just one thing, there is a line-break after close bracket. Which character should I put into regex to remove this line-break? I tried \n and [\n] but don't removed behind line.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to be a one liner, you can use 'grep' to get the line numbers, and then use 'sed' to delete the entire stanza from the line numbers.

See [Delete specific line number(s) from a text file using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112469/delete-specific-line-numbers-from-a-text-file-using-sed)