# How to delete every nth lines in a txt file?

Tags: matlab

I have a txt file (ANSYS 1ST principle nodal stress list) and there are almost 16k lines inside of it. I wanna delete specific lines for example 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, 39th, 40th, 41th, 42th, 43th, etc. I dont need to search anything, i know which lines be deleted. is there anybody help?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Did you see this ? https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/159783-how-to-delete-specific-lines-from-a-txt-file

Comment: @MohammadrezaKhatami, that code does not work to my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the most efficient way but this works:

```
data_file = 'data.txt';
lines_to_skip = [1:5, 39:43];

fid = fopen(data_file);
ii = 0;
while ~feof(fid)
    ii = ii + 1;
    file_content{ii} = fgetl(fid);
end

lines = true(1,ii);
lines(lines_to_skip) = false;
fid = fopen(data_file,'w');
fprintf(fid,'%s\r\n',file_content{lines});
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using linux you can use that command:

```
sed -i '2d' data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is tagged as Matlab, but doing this inside Matlab is going to be painful because it doesn't usually offer a convenient way to remove bytes *in the middle* of a file, so you'd have to write some code to write the text to a new file, skipping lines as appropriate.

If you're on a UNIX system it'll be much easier using sed. There's [a great answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112469/delete-specific-line-numbers-from-a-text-file-using-sed) explaining how to do that. The key command is:

```
# To delete line 10 and 12:
sed -i -e '10d;12d' your-file.txt
```