# How to iterate lines from a file and read fields into variables

Tags: bash, shell, loops, awk

I have a file `hotfix_final` that looks like this:

```
https://download.abc.com  06/24/2019
https://download.abc.com  06/26/2019
https://download.abc.com  07/05/2019
```

I need to write a shell script that reads the file line by line and then takes the date that is next to the link into a variable so that I can compare it to the current date. If the dates are equal and `usage_type = 4`, I need the script to wget the link.

What I tried so far:

```sh
usage_type=$( cat /opt/abc/ps/usage.txt )
current_date=$( date +%x )
lines=$( wc -l /home/abc/hotfix_final | awk '{print $1}' )

count=0

while $count <= $lines; do

    hf_link=$( awk if( NR=$count ) '{print $1}' hotfix_final )
    relase_date=$( awk if( NR=$count ) '{print $2}' hotfix_final )
    count=$(( count+1 ))

done < hotfix_final
```

In the above example, I used:

- `$lines` to show the max number of lines to read.
- `$hf_link` to get the link
- `$release_date` to get the date next to $hf_link

Now, I am not sure how to write the part that checks whether `$usage_type == 4` and `$current_date = $relase_date`  are true, and if so, wget the link. This needs to be done individually for each line of the file.

Comment: There are many many many mistakes in this script. **(1)**: quote your awk properly : `awk '{if( NR==$count ) print $1}'` **(2)**  if statements should do comparisons not assignments: `if(NR == $count)` **(3)** shell variables should be passed to awk correctly : `awk -v count=$count '{if(NR == count) print $1}'` **(4)** don't parse a file in bash with a while loop the way you do:, just use a proper while in combination with read, you can skip the awk to extract the variables. See answer of [Léa Gris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57608652/8344060)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38627863/874188 for why reading line numbers is very often an antipattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be done with a few fixes to your script:

- You need to take care of quoting your variables to avoid values from being split on space or any characters listed in the `$IFS` variable.
- `date +%x` would return a date with a different format on a system with different locale setting in the `$LC_TIME` environment variable.
  The `%x` format would be `MM/DD/YYY` when setting `LC_TIME=en_US`, but there is a tiny (while admittedly very unlikely) chance that the `en_US` locale may not be available to the system.
  It is then preferable to use an explicit locale-independent format of `+%d/%m/%Y`, to be safe on the date format.

Here is a fixed version:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Early exit this script if the usage.txt file does not contain the value 4
grep -Fqx 4 /opt/abc/ps/usage.txt || exit

# Store current date in the MM/DD/YYYY format
current_date="$(date +%d/%m/%Y)"

# Iterate each line from hotfix_final
# and read the variables hf_link and release_date
while read -r hf_link release_date; do
  if [ "$current_date" = "$release_date" ]; then
    wget "$hf_link"
  fi
done </home/abc/hotfix_final # Set the file as input for the whole while loop
```

Comment: but how does shell know that for each row of the ```hotfix_final``` file ```$hf_link``` represents the links while ```$release_date``` represents the dates next to the links?

Comment: The `read` command reads one line at a time. Then when presented with multiple variables to read, it uses spaces or the characters defined into the `$IFS` environment variable to delimit fields within the line and assign values to variables in the same order as the read variables arguments.

Comment: You want to exit early if `usage_type` is not 4, instead of compare it again and again inside the loop.

Comment: You only moved it, it's still being compared on every iteration.

Comment: Sorry for the `fgrep -f` typo in my answer, you want to fix that here too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a refactoring of the accepted answer to avoid the fugly `while read -r` loop.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

grep -Fqx 4 /opt/abc/ps/usage.txt || exit

awk -v current_date="$(date +%d/%m/%Y)" '
    $2 == current_date { print $1 }' /home/abc/hotfix_final |
xargs -r -n 1 wget
```

The `-r` option to `xargs` is a GNU extension; if you don't have it, it's not critical, but helps avoid an error message when the Awk script does not produce any output.

In your next project, you want to make sure you use a less insane date format in computer-readable files.

Comment: I guess you could do it in a stand-alone awk script with its own `#!/usr/bin/env awk` shebang

Comment: I started with the `usage.txt` handling inside the Awk script too but it made less sense to someone who is probably not very familiar with Awk so I wanted to keep it very simple and structured.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU Parallel):

```
[ $(<usageFile) -eq 4 ] && 
parallel -a fixFile -C' +' [ {2} = $(date +%m/%d/%Y) ] \&\& wget {1}
```

Use `test` to interrogate the useage file and if set to `4` use parallel to complete the task. Parallel uses the `fix` file  and the `-C` option with the regexp of one or more spaces to name the columns in the file `{1}` as the url and `{2}` as the date. Test is used again to check the date column against todays date and a match will `wget` the url.